# Ubuntu - adduser / useradd both ask for password to be set, can force a script to bypass this?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, scripting, useradd

I have a script that works fine on Centos because useradd doesnt require a password to be set there and then, but the same script doesnt work on ubuntu servers as it requires this info.

I ideally want to force no password set on my script for the ubuntu servers or add a line where it sets the password during the useradd command.

If I just add sudo passwd *user* to my script this will only take effect after the useradd command which is too late.

Any ideas?

Comment: For the Deb/Ubu `adduser` command you can pass `--disabled-password`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man adduser`:

```
--disabled-password
Like --disabled-login, but logins are still possible (for example using SSH RSA keys) but not using password authentication.
```

The default behaviour on `useradd` is to disable the password, so that one should already work.

Comment: perfect, now my next issue are these requests. Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
    Full Name []: 
    Room Number []: 
    Work Phone []: 
    Home Phone []: 
    Other []: 
Is the information correct? [Y/n]     How can I get around this information being asked for?

Comment: @MattB, Ask a new, separate question! :-D. The more questions you ask the more reputation you gain on the S.E. network, which lets you do more things. So it's good to keep things simple and separate. Also, `adduser` is a pretty Debian-specific utility, so you may want to switch over to askubuntu.com instead. Chances are, the question's already been answered.

Comment: Honestly though, if you're doing things with a script, it's probably better to do it with `useradd`, which can do things non-interactively much better than `adduser` can.  I think `adduser` (being a perl script), was never intended to be scripted, but is just a helper for manual use.

Comment: @MattB - See http://askubuntu.com/questions/94060/run-adduser-non-interactively

Comment: as you can tell im new to all of this. But good news is I found the answer earlier and now my script works on both Centos and Ubuntu. Im started to hate ubuntu now also.... :P

Comment: @Dale Anderson - If you then add a password to a user created with `adduser ... ----disabled-password USER`, will the password no longer be disabled?

Comment: @Wimateeka correct.